# tornadoweb gzip=True not working under supervisord and nginx

Tags: nginx, gzip, tornado, supervisord

While working with tornado, I've discovered gzip=True feature, which works fine while running application from command line, below settings:

```
define("port", default=settings.LISTEN_PORT, help="run on the given port", type=int)
define("debug", default=True, help="run in debug mode", type=bool)
define("dont_optimize_static_content", default=False,
       help="Don't combine static resources", type=bool)
define("dont_embed_static_url", default=False,
       help="Don't put embed the static URL in static_url()", type=bool)

tornado.options.parse_command_line()
tornado.options.options['log_file_prefix'].set('/var/log/tmp.log')

app_settings = dict(
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    xsrf_cookies=False,
    gzip=True,
    debug=True,
)
```

However, deploying app with supervisord/nginx responses from tornado servers are not gziped.

```
[program:app-8001]
command=python /var/app/server/app.py --port=8001 --logging=debug ----dont_optimize_static_content=False
directory=/var/app/server/
stderr_logfile = /var/log/app-stderr.log
stderr_logfile_backups=10
stdout_logfile = /var/log/app-stdout.log
stdout_logfile_backups=10
process_name=%(program_name)s
loglevel=debug
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not that I think it's your bug, but you've got too many '----' on the supervisor command.

Comment: sorry, its not this...

Answer (score 1):

By default nginx doesn't do HTTP/1.1 requests when it proxies requests to Tornado (or anything for that matter).  Tornado requires HTTP/1.1 support for returning gzip'ed content.

Significant code fragment from web.py

```
def __init__(self, request):
    self._gzipping = request.supports_http_1_1() and \
        "gzip" in request.headers.get("Accept-Encoding", "")
```

It should be overrideable by adding the following to your config file - however it doesn't work on my instance.

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```